# Giving inputs to google data flow REST API

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

What are the mandatory parameters to google data flow REST API - dataflow.projects.jobs.create ? Please provide with sample data.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/Google%20Dataflow%20API%20v1b3/dataflow/v1b3/dataflow.projects.jobs.create

Answer (score 2):

The `dataflow.projects.jobs.create` API is not intended for direct use. Instead, Dataflow jobs should be created using one of the Dataflow SDKs. See the [quickstart guides](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts) for Java or Python for some getting started information.

The [Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview) API may be sufficient for your needs.